# Why am I only able to get the 6 first result of google maps (scraping)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

For a personnal data science project I would like to scrape the data of google maps.
I'm doing that using python and selenium and I'm facing an weird issue, I'm only able to extract 6 results of each page (a page can contains till 20 results).

I share with you what I've done so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import string
import openpyxl
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Loading Selenium Webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

# Opening Google maps
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
time.sleep(3)
#Closing the google consent form
button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div/div/button')
button.click()

searchbox=driver.find_element(By.ID,'searchboxinput')
location= "Paris"
searchbox.send_keys(location)
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
cancelbut=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'gsst_a')
cancelbut.click()
searchbox.send_keys("ASSURANCE")
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)

# Locating the results section
while 1==1 :
    #Class name of a section
    entries = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'lI9IFe')
    print(str(entries))



    # Prepare the excel file using the Openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/ac/Desktop/plombier.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
    #sheet = wb[sheetname]
    #sheet.title = "plombier"
    i=0
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.text)
        print(i)
        i+=1
        # Empty list
        labels = []
        # Extracting the Name, adress, Phone, and website:

        name = entry.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.qBF1Pd').text
        #adress = entry.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/span[2]').text
        #phone = entry.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/span[3]/jsl/span[2]').text
        print(name)
        try:
            webcontainer = entry.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'section-result-action-container')
            website = entry.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').get_attribute("href")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            website = "No website could be found"
        print(website)

        # Try/except  to write the extracted info in the Excel file pass if doessn't exist
        try:
            sheet.append([location, name, website])
        except IndexError:
            pass

    # saving the excel file
    wb.save("C:/Users/ac/Desktop/plombier.xlsx")
    time.sleep(4)
    pagesuivantebut = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ppdPk-Ej1Yeb-LgbsSe-tJiF1e')
    pagesuivantebut.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Am I using the wrong class name to find my section result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you do an error, you dont have 20 records at max by page, you'll see that if you count the number of records `print(len(entries))`, you'll have 7 or 9 records

the reason is easy to understand, google maps updates the number of searches if you scroll down and in this case, you'll have all records (> 20 because some enterprises always appears at the beginning , they have paid to be on the top)

hope that helps you to investigate more and change your coding

i have done a little video available 2 days

download it for better quality : [googlemaps probme](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EpEY-Yqyg-vgZnvH05xZo2PVHVezYLeK/view)

Comment: Yeah I was able to do it by scrolling down. Now I'm just looking how to get each number of phone.

Comment: this xpath should do the job: //span[@jstcache='1117' and string-length(text()) = '14' and not (contains(text(),'Opens'))]

Comment: phone = entry.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@jstcache='1117' and string-length(text()) = '14' and not (contains(text(),'Opens'))]").text  didn't work. I have an error

Comment: I think that the jstcache is something that move at each request

Comment: ok..if you have again a problem dont hesitate to open a new questio,, i'll see